# A tool to make the division of C++ code into .h and .cpp files transparent to the programmer

Tags: c++, ide

C++ was the the first language I've learnt so dividing source code into .h and .cpp files seemed obvious - but having learnt C# and Java they now appear to me terribly clumsy. They might have been useful back in the 60s, maybe still even in 80s, but in the era of modern tools, such as IDEs with section folding, and documentation generators, they seem obsolete.

Anyway, my question is: is there a tool which makes the presence of these two kind of files transparent to the programmer? For example by letting the coder write the definition of a method seemingly in the header file but actually saving it to the .cpp file?

(I know one can try to write a C++ program solely in header files but AFAIK this is not considered best practice, makes the program build even longer and makes it virtually impossible for two classes to reference each other.)

Comment: Yeah, they are important to the compiler, headers can be shipped with libraries compiled into machine code and so on - that's why I'm not asking how to get rid of them completely. I'm asking how to make the edition of C++ code which is divided into these two kind of files easier.

Comment: Relying on an IDE region/code folding/wizardry/etc indicates bad or lazy programming habits to me. Hiding the dirt behind folded sections is by no means a sane thing.

Comment: @Mat the OP understands the point of headers, but would like to know if an editor exists which will present them as one source (e.g. presenting the definitions inline, even though they may exist in the .cpp). at least, that's how i read it. consider for example, the ability of an ide to dynamically display documentation inline/contextually, then take that concept further to present declaration and definition in one editor. then the editor abstracts the actual changes to separate files.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Header files are an abomination, there's nothing wrong with using some fairly extreme means to get rid of them.

Comment: @DeadMG: Headers should be written as cleanly as possible, so as to be able to read at a glance the contents of a class. Maintaining a database of some sort to automatically generate them is much less flexible than what headers can offer, and it would be especially painful if you had to write the tool yourself. The simple copy/paste mechanism is actually very flexible, and the only really bothering thing with it is that one simple change to some class declaration will trigger a huge recompilation. But even this can be taken care of.

Comment: Given the kind of magic that is often performed using #defines in header files, I'm not sure making the header files transparent to the developer is a good idea in general... things can already be confusing enough without complicating them further by withholding necessary information from the developer.  Maybe the tool could be smart enough to only hide headers that don't have side effects, or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any that makes the division into source/header completely transparent.

I do, however, know of some that make it considerably easier to handle. For example, Visual Assist X will let write your entire class in a header, then select member functions, and move them to a source file (i.e., a .cpp file).

That's not a complete cure (by any means), but it can/does make them much more bearable anyway.

Personally, I think it would be interesting to get rid of files completely, and instead use something like a database directly -- i.e., you have a database of functions, where the source code to that function is one column, object code another, internal compiler information about how to use it yet another, and so on. This would also make integrating version control pretty straightforward (basically just a stored transaction log).

Answer (score 4):

The discussion that I am seeing in the question, comments and the comments to the other answer seem to focus on the textual representation of the components. From the point of view of plain text, it makes sense to remove the headers altogether.

On the other hand, there is a second level to the separation of headers and cpp files, which is separating the interface from the implementation, and in doing so, removing implementation details from the interface.

This happens in different ways, in the simplest level *how* you implement a particular piece of functionality is irrelevant to the users of your component[*]. In many cases, you can have more types and functions in the .cpp file that are used just as details of implementation. Additionally, if you decide to implement a particular functionality directly or by depending on another library is a detail of implementation and should not leak to your users.

That separation might or might not be easy to implement in a tool that managed the separation of files automatically, and cannot be done by those that like the use of *header only* libraries.

Where some of you are claiming that there is no point in having to *Go to definition*, and would like to see the code altogether, what I see is the flexibility of deciding what parts of your component are *details* that should not be known by users. In many IDEs (and, heck, even in vim) there is a single keystroke combination that will take you from one to the other. In IDEs you can *refactor* the signature of the function and have the IDE apply the changes to both the header and the implementation (sometimes even to the uses)...

If you were to have a tool provide a unified view of both the header and implementation, it would probably be much harder to make the tool knowledgable of what parts of the code you are writing are part of the interface or the implementation, and the decisions that the tool might have could have an impact on the generated program.

The separate compilation model has its disadvantages but also advantages, and I feel that the discussion that is being held here is just scratching the surface of deeper design decisions.

[*] There seems to be quite a few people that believe that each class should have its own header and .cpp files, and I disagree, each header represents a component that might be a single class, or multiple classes and free functions the separation of code in files is part of the *design*, and in a single component you might have one or more public types together with possibly none or more internal types.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, especially with the last paragraph. Also, C++ is way more complicated than the "everything is a class" approach of C#/Java; this renders any tool pointless. You also have functions, function templates, class templates, typedefs, enumerations, etc, which may have several *roles* (actual class templates, traits classes, utilities, higher order functions, functors, "type functions", etc). Good judgment is the rule here, separating headers by concerns, possibly `#including` a bunch of them in another one is very a flexible approach which has no parallel in the c#/java world.

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, like the header files in C++, because they can serve as a "table of contents" of a sort, which gives you a quick overview of a class. This is, of course, assuming that you keep your headers short, and put the implementation of most functions into the .cpp.

Also, you can get plugins for Visual Studio that will move the implementation of a member function from the header into a .cpp for you.  That, plus the "go to definition" and "go to declaration" commands in Visual Studio make headers very helpful for navigating a large code base.

Comment: Comments or autogenerated dependency graphs serve that function better.

Comment: You are crazy. Header files must go.

Comment: @DeadMG: Running a Doxygen-like tool can also help.

Comment: I would argue, if you fold your C# methods into definitions what you get is fairly identical to a C++ header. Except instead of "going to definition" you simply unfold the method you want to see. And except that "table of contents" didn't take any extra labour to create. Anyway, what are the plugins you mention?

Comment: @lampak: And your argument would be missing the point that the *implementation* of your type is leaking... if your function uses a third party library, by having it in the header you are making that implementation detail matter to the users... If you have a tool that splits into header and implementation, then the tool needs to guess whether that dependency is to be shown in the interface or not, and it would have to know whether you to add the proper includes or forward declarations...

Answer (score 0):

Headers are pretty fundamental to the current compilation model of C++. I think there are things that would be a bit difficult to express without exposing the programmer directly to the header/cpp split. For example, in certain circumstances there's a significant difference between:

```
// header
class Foo {
    Foo() = default;
}
```

and

```
// header
class Foo {
    Foo();
};

// cpp
Foo::Foo() = default;
```

Despite that I think it would be worthwhile to think about improving the compilation model or making it easier to deal with.

For example, I can imagine a 'code bubbles' style IDE where the programmer writes definitions in code bubbles, and then groups bubbles together into translation units. The programmer would mark definitions as 'exported' to make them available to other TUs and for each TU he'd select exported items from other units to import. And all the while the IDE is maintaining it's own code bubble representation of the program, and when you  build it generates the actual cpp files necessary for passing off to the compiler, creating forward declarations, etc. as needed. The cpp files would just be an intermediate build product.

There would be subtleties like the one I showed above though, and I'm not sure how the IDE I described would deal with that.